# JSF 1.2 : h:graphicImage appending jsessionid

Tags: jsf-1.2

Am using JSF 1.2

I have an image which should be clickable. Below is how I have coded,

```
<h:commandLink value="" action="#{myBean.myMethod}>
   <h:graphicImage value="image-location-in-webserver" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Am using `h:commandLink` because on click of this image I have to do some business validations and hence I need to call a method in bean.

My bean is `session` scoped. I can't go with request scope because of some other problems.

I tried `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` setting it to client instead of server.

Even then when my page is rendered, image is not getting redered because jsessionid is getting appended to url like below when viewed in web developer.

```
http:/myDomail/static-files/images/myImage.jpg;jsessionid=77F2A5D24CF1D5C3C4882778BC521263.node1
```

If jsessionid is not appended, my image gets rendered.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, 
I tried URL rewrite in urlrewrite.xml as mentioned below

(http://javatechworld.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-to-remove-jsessionid-from-url-java.html)

It didnt work and its affecting other places. I wrote a rewrite rule in Apache web server. Didnt help !

Comment: Please see the solution at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349064/jsessionid-how-to-avoid-jsessionid-xxx-on-the-first-call-to-a-page-it-works